# KVC get lastPathComponent from string which is the property of object

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, key-value-coding

I have e.g. 5 `MyFile` objects in my `NSArray`. Each of these 5 objects has property `path`.

```
MyFile *myFile ...;

NSString path = myMyFile.path;
```

So using KVC I can get the properties form all my 5 objects in the array:

```
NSArray *folders = [[PNFolder MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate] valueForKey:@"path"];
```

so code above will return `path`s instead of `MyFile` objects and this is ok for me.

But, how can I using the `lastPathComponent` here as well to make my array return me just folder name instead of full path. I mean using KVC. or do I need to write cycle?

Comment: that shouldn't work as you use valueForKey on the array instead of valueForKeyPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use valueForKeyPath with the array

```
NSArray *folderNames = [[PNFolder MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate] valueForKeyPath:@"path.lastPathComponent"];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is KVC, not KVO (coding, not observing), though in the case of `NSArray` it's an explicitly stated method (`valueForKey:`). It calls the method on the destination object(s) and returns the contents. So, you can use it with `lastPathComponent`.

Indeed, you should be able to use pure KVC via `valueForKeyPath:` with `path.lastPathComponent`.